# Are matrix Fisher r.v.s closed under multiplication?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, rotation

With appropriate parameters, a matrix Fisher distribution provides a distribution over SO(3) (i.e. over rotations in $R^3$).  See [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179949/two-matrix-fisher-distributions-on-so3) for a few notes describing the distribution.

Suppose that $X$ is a matrix Fisher random variable with parameter $F$, and $Y$ is a matrix Fisher random variable with parameter $G$.  If I treat $X$ and $Y$ as $3\times 3$ rotation matrices, I can consider their product, the random variable $Z=XY$.

Question: Does $Z$ have a matrix Fisher distribution?  If so, what is the parameter?

I had hoped to find this addressed in Mardia and Jupp's "Directional Statistics", but no luck as far as I could tell.  There's also a comment in [Suvorova, "Bayesian Recursive Estimation on the Rotation Group", 2013](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6638900) that points out that since rotation matrices do not, in general commute, then the mean of the product of matrix Fisher random variables is not necessarily the product of the mean.